# Summation in C using Function

Tags: c

I was assigned to solve this problem using a function in C. I think I am going along the right lines as with the way the equation is set up now I get each individual instance of the summation, but I am stumped as to how to get the function to add the function together in the main function. Don't mind the naming convention, it is what's required for the assignment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double doublef(double x,int i) {
    double equation;
        equation = pow(-1, i + 1) * (pow(x, i) / i);
        return equation;
}
int main() {
    for (int i = 1;i < 20;i++) {
        double number1=doublef(0.3, i);
        printf("f(0.3)=%f", number1);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Equation][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW8DK.png

Comment: Please clarify what is required. Do you want to keep adding the returned values in number1 in a loop?

Comment: Yes, the goal is to add each result when i is increased. So the first result is .3 and the second is -.045, so adding them gets .255, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double doublef(double x,int i) {
    double equation;
        equation = pow(-1, i + 1) * (pow(x, i) / i);
        return equation;
}
int main() {
    double number1=0; 
    for (int i = 1;i < 20;i++) {
        number1+=doublef(0.3, i);
    }
    printf("f(0.3)=%f", number1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This almost works for me. I keep receiving an error that the number1 variable is initialized.

Comment: https://imgur.com/2jHaZvb Here is a link to a screenshot

Comment: `double number1=0;` declare variable like this

Comment: That fixed the issue now, along with had to create a new file. Thank you for your answer.